# How do you find out which packages installed has `apache2` as its dependency?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, nginx, apt-get

When installing softwares like nginx on an Ubuntu 12.04 server, `apache2` appears to be installed as one of the dependency which is not what we need.

**Question:** How do you find out which packages installed has `apache2` as its dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
sudo apt-rdepends apache2
```

This will show the packages and the version needed.

Comment: On Debian Bookworm, circa 2024, the command would be `sudo apt rdepends apache2`. Notice that `rdepends` is sub-command to apt like `install`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apt-rdepends to traverse dependencies forwards or backwards

http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/apt-rdepends_1.3.0-2_all.deb.html

alternatively, there is

```
apt-cache rdepends packagename
```

from here https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-package-dependees-reverse-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/lib/dpkg/status
```

this has the deb dependency list.  each package in this file has a dependencies section if they have deps.  and you can just pull a list of those and look for the apache2 depends.

here is some terrible code for pulling that status file into a searchable sqlitedb in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import os
import re
import sqlite3
import sys
import time
import traceback

from dpkg import parse
from dpkg import poll

def db_init(status_file):
    # poll status file
    status_obj = poll.poll(status_file)

    # initialize sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    db_create(conn)

    # parse status fileobject, load into database
    db_status_load(conn, status_obj)

    # kill that big string obj
    del status_obj

    # return ready database handle
    return conn

def db_query(conn, query):
    db_resp = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
    return db_resp

def db_create(conn):
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY;')
    c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;')

    # two tables packages, and a dependency index 
    c.execute('create table if not exists packages (packageid integer primary key autoincrement, packagename text, description blob);')
    c.execute('create table if not exists depends (packageid int, dependencyid int, alternate int);')
    c.execute('create table if not exists alternates (packageid int, dependencyid int, alternateid int);')
    conn.commit()

def db_listPackages(conn):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from packages')
    rows = c.fetchall()
    return rows

def db_descPackage(conn, package_name):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from packages where packagename=?', (package_name,))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    return rows

def db_namePackage(conn, package_id):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from packages where packageid=?', (package_id,))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    if len(rows) < 1:
        # No package name for that ID
        package_name = "NULL"
    else:
        package_name = str(rows[0][1])
    return package_name

def db_idPackage(conn, package_name):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from packages where packagename=?', (str(package_name),))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    if len(rows) < 1:
        # No corresponding package in our status db by that name
        package_id = 0
    else:
        package_id = int(rows[0][0])
    return package_id

def db_depsPackage(conn, package_id):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from depends where packageid=?', (package_id,))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    return rows

def db_indepsPackage(conn, package_id):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from depends where dependencyid=?', (package_id,))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    return rows

def db_getAlternates(conn, package_id, dependency_id):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from alternates where dependencyid=? AND packageid=?', (dependency_id, package_id))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    return rows

def db_status_load(conn, status_obj):
    c = conn.cursor()
    # render json datastruct from string object
    status_dict = parse.parse(status_obj)
    package_name = package_description = ""
    package_depends = []

    # stage packages info from status_dict
    # populate packages table
    for packages in status_dict['Packages']:
        # define package name
        package_name = packages
        # print "inserting \033[34m %s \033[0m :\n" % package_name
        for idx,stuff in enumerate(status_dict['Packages'][packages]):
            if stuff.has_key("Description"): 
                # define package description
                package_description = stuff['Description']

        # execute insertion query
        b = sqlite3.Binary(package_description)
        c.execute('insert into packages (packagename, description) values (?,?)', (package_name, b) )

    conn.commit()

    # populate dependency table
    for packages in status_dict['Packages']:
        package_name = packages
        # print "inserting depends and alternates for \033[31m %s \033[0m :\n" % package_name
        for stuff in status_dict['Packages'][packages]:
            if stuff.has_key("Depends"):
                dep_string = stuff['Depends']
                dep_string = dep_string.replace(" ", "")
                dep_array = dep_string.split(',')
                package_id = db_idPackage(conn, package_name)
                for dep in dep_array:
                    dep = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', dep)
                    if "|" in dep: 
                        alternates = dep.split('|')
                        deporig = alternates[0]
                        for idx, alternate in enumerate(alternates):
                            if idx > 0:
                                alternate_id = db_idPackage(conn, alternate)
                                dependency_id = db_idPackage(conn, deporig)
                                # print "\033[33m ALTERNATE: %s, %s, %s \033[0m \n" % (package_id, dependency_id, alternate_id)
                                c.execute('insert into alternates (packageid, dependencyid, alternateid) values (?,?,?)', 
                                          (package_id, dependency_id, alternate_id) )
                            else:
                                dependency_id = db_idPackage(conn, deporig)
                                c.execute('insert into depends (packageid, dependencyid, alternate) values (?, ?, ?)',
                                          (package_id, dependency_id, 1) )
                    else:
                        dependency_id = db_idPackage(conn, dep)
                        c.execute('insert into depends (packageid, dependencyid, alternate) values (?, ?, ?)',
                                  (package_id, dependency_id, 0) ) 

    # commit changes to database
    conn.commit()

    return 0
```

Answer (score -1):

RPM-based distributions allow this by a simple call of the basic rpm utility:

```
rpm -q --whatrequires apache2
```

I am certain the apt package manager used in Ubuntu offers something similar. I suggest you read its man page...

Comment: unfortunately ubuntu uses `apt`

Comment: @hek2mgl Which is exactly what I stated in the answer. Did you even bother to read it?

Comment: So how would this answer the problem?

Comment: @hek2mgl At least _try_ to understand what I wrote.

Comment: @hek2mgl Certainly better, since it actually helps, than not answering and bashing on others. BYE.